# How can I get a combined patch from 2/multiple commits?

Tags: git

Say, the revision history:
    a1 <-- b2 <-- c3 <-- d4 <-- e5

I need to get a combined patch from these 2:

```
git diff b2^!    
git diff d4^!
```

Pretty much like the effect of 2 cherry-picks. Is there any easy way to just get the patch?

Answer (score 0):

Just using `git show b2 d4` could get the patch including the commit info.

> `git show b2 d4 --pretty=` will print the only patch